# Change date format according to existing record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

I want to change the date format from `2016-04-04T00:00:00` to `dd/mm/yyyy`. [Target_Hire_Date] is the column that I wanted to update. My code can shows the result but have an error. Can you please help me? Thank you so much!

```
select convert(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(date,[Target_Hire_Date],103),103)
from [master].[dbo].[1A]
```

Error:
[image: error]

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: converting to date doesn't require the extra parameter.

Comment: what do u mean by doesn't require the extra parameter? @ZLK

Comment: As in, you can remove the "103" when converting to date. e.g. `CONVERT(DATE, [Target_Hire_Date])`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Today Date To Convert dd/mm/yyyy Format

SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(date,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME),103),103)
```

Comment: Your code is working but got error 'Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' Do u know how to fix it?

Comment: This is the existing record and the datatype is nvarchar(255) 2016-04-04T00:00:00 and I want to change to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @meow exactly. The format is wrong in that `SQL Server` is unable to accurately guess the date format from the string. Instead of altering a date that is already a date, work on making sure your strings used in comparison are in fact properly formatted. You can always verify with `TRY_CONVERT` if need be as TRY will not fail the query be return a `NULL` (note: `CAST` lets `SQL` guess, and may not be accurate or dependable on every system)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
       SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Target_Hire_Date],103)
       FROM [master].[dbo].[1A]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Dt NVARCHAR(255)
SET @Dt = '2016-04-25T00:00:00'
SELECT  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, @Dt) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 103), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

use cast first to convert your date in smalldatetime and then use convert to convert in dd/mm/yyyy

code as below

```
select convert(varchar(10),cast('2016-04-04T00:00:00' as smalldatetime),103) date
```